# How to show modal popup after submitting form using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, i have created a form and wantedto display modal after submitting the form saying "Successfully Submitted". But i don't know how to give popup after submitting the form.

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Input
            transparent
            label="First Name"
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            className="box"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
          <Form.Input
            transparent
            label="Last Name"
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            className="box"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
          <Form.Input
            transparent
            label="Email"
            type="text"
            name="email"
            className="box"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />
          <Button>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
```

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-silence-fgq2j)

I want to pass message variable to modal inorder to display message if the form submitted successfully.

Can anyone help me in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you just have to conditionally render `ShowModal` and pass event handler `close` to it.

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import axios from "axios";

import ShowModal from "./ShowModal"

export default class AddForm extends React.Component {
  {......same content........}
  onCancel = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({ message: "" }))
  }

  render() {
    const { message } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {.....}
        </Form>
        <ShowModal close={this.onCancel} message={message} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
And in ShowModal.jsx:

```
<Modal open={!!message}>
  {......}
</Modal>
```

Comment: Hi, But i could not able to get the pop after implementing this code

Comment: I've edited the answer, let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: :) Modal is appearing, can you help me in closing modal ?

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#variations-close-icon) you can pass `onClose` prop to Modal, i.e. `onClose={this.props.close}`.

Comment: Did you pass `close` prop to `ShowModal`?

Comment: Maybe pass `closeIcon` to `Modal` to show close icon on Modal.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-microservice-d4znm，example code

Comment: `onClose={this.onActionClick}` pass this to `Modal` component.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali - Okay, This Works! Thanks :)

Comment: @gu mingfeng - This Works, Thanks :)